# Explain this type-coercion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, type-coercion

I have read that when we compare object with a number type-coercion happens. ToPrimitive on object gets called which then calls valueOf and if required toString. But I not able to get my head around how its actually working in the code given below

```
[ null ] == 0             // true
[ undefined ] == 0        // true
[ ] == 0                  // true
[ "-0" ] == 0             // true

[ false ] == 0            // false
[ true ] == 0             // false
```

> **How is [ false ] == 0 is false but [ null ] , [ undefined ] is true**

Comment: When coercing an Array, JavaScript can only do one thing: `toString`. Which is an alias of `join` by default. Array.join normally calls `toString` on each item, but it has a special behavior for *null* and *undefined* which are not boxable: just output an empty string. So you get an empty string, which, coerced to number, becomes zero. Whereas booleans have a `toString` method which outputs "true" or "false".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because calling `Number([false])`, which results in `Number('false')`, returns `NaN`, whereas `''` (empty or only white-space), `null` and `undefined` initialize a `Number` as `0`. The `Number` [wrapper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive#Primitive_wrapper_objects_in_JavaScript) returns a primitive value.

> *Except for `null` and `undefined`, all primitive values have object equivalents that wrap around the primitive values.*

As Touffy noted in the comments, before calling the wrapper, the array needs to be resolved by calling `toString` on the value. Once the string value is determined, the wrapper handles the parsing.

```js
Number([0])         // [0].toString()         => Number("0")     => 0
Number([undefined]) // [undefined].toString() => Number("")      => 0
Number([null])      // [null].toString()      => Number("")      => 0 
Number([false])     // [false].toString()     => Number("false") => NaN
```

Both `null` and `undefined` are valid arguments for producing a `Number` primitive, because they are the absence of a value. Blank or empty strings are also considered empty values. Since the string value of `'false'` and `false` (boolean) values are non-empty and not numeric, you will get `NaN`.

**Note:** This is slightly different from how integer parsing works.

```js
parseInt('0')     // 0
parseInt('')      // NaN
parseInt('false') // NaN
```

You can check out [`string_number_conversions_internal.h`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:base/strings/string_number_conversions_internal.h) over at the Chromium Code Search to see how parsing works for strings.

Comment: That would be a bit less incorrect if you removed the `new`. `Number(x)`  returns a primitive *number*, whereas `new Number(x)` returns an *instance of Number*.

Comment: @Touffy I believe I worded it better.

Comment: yeah, well… except for the missing step where the array is coerced to a string before being coerced back to a number.